# Return radiobutton's value

Tags: javascript, html

I checked for duplicates but didn't find an exactly same problem so here we go. I have two radio-buttons and I need to return their values upon form submission. The problem is that when I click the submit button I always get the same radio-button value. Here is some code:

```
<div id="automatic">
        <p>Title1
            <input type="radio" id ="mode" name="mod" value="auto" >
        </p>           
    </div>

    <div id="selection">
        <p>Title2
            <input type="radio" id ="mode" name="mod" value="nonauto" >
        </p>           
    </div>

    <form id="search" action="test.jsp" method="GET" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('search_text').value.length < 1) return false;">
        <input id="search_text" type="text" name="q">
        <input id="searchButton" type="submit" onclick="displayRadio()" value="Search" autocomplete="off" size="115">
    </form>
```

And here is the Javascript code:

```
function displayRadio() {
        alert(document.getElementById("mode").value)
}
```

Comment: That is invalid HTML code, you can't have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute (i.e. the `id="mode"`)

Comment: If I have different id's the radio-buttons aren't mutually exclusive anymore. Any suggestions on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: why all your input tags doesn't have an end tag? You can't have same id values for radio button. 'name' attribute can be same, but not the 'id'.

Comment: It's the name attribute that makes them mutually exclusive, right?

Comment: I really don't get the negative votes. This isn't an HTML contest, I am supposed to deliver wrong code. Whatever.

Comment: Right, thanks javabeangrinder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different ids and use your function to lookup which of them is checked and return the value of that.

```
function displayRadio() {
    var modeauto = document.getElementById('modeauto');
    var modenoauto = document.getElementById('modenoauto');
    var value = modeauto.checked ? modeauto.value : modenoauto.value;
    alert(value);
}
```

*I would recommend using jQuery for simplicity though.*